# Retrieve all items within JSON instead of just by index

Tags: javascript, jquery

Below is an example JSON object:

```
{"Group": {"Subscriptions": [{"ZoneId": "51"},{"ZoneId": "3573"}]}}
```

I can retrieve a particular 'ZoneId' using something like this for the first index:

```
obj.Group.Subscriptions[0].ZoneId
```

But is it possible to retrieve an array of all 'ZoneId's?
For example, something like the following (if you can imagine that working like a get-all wildcard)

```
obj.Group.Subscriptions[*].ZoneId
```

Does such a syntax exist? or is there another way to retrieve all 'Zone ID's within "Subscriptions"?
(There could be any number of ZoneIds)

I'm using jQuery/Javascript to work with this data.

Comment: JSON is just text. The question is about dealing with *JavaScript objects*, not text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `map` to extract what you need.

```
obj.Group.Subscriptions.map(function(x){return x.ZoneId});
//^ ["51", "3573"]
```

This is also known as "pluck", with [Underscore](http://underscorejs.org/) you could do:

```
_.pluck(obj.Group.Subscriptions, 'ZoneId');
```

Comment: Be aware that if you have to support IE8 (or even lower), `Array.prototype.map` is not supported (http://kangax.github.io/es5-compat-table/#Array.prototype.map). Thus using Underscore is the safe option (and it's a great library).

Answer (score 0):

If you're also using the [UnderscoreJS](http://underscorejs.org/) library you can use the `pluck` function like this:

```
_.pluck(obj.Group.Subscriptions, 'ZoneId');
```

which in your case would give you

```
["51", "3573"]
```

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this:

```
var obj = 
{
    "Group": {
        "Subscriptions": [{"ZoneId": "51"}, {"ZoneId": "3573" }], 
        "GetAllSubscriptions": function() { 
            return this.Subscriptions.map(function(item){ return item.ZoneId; });  
        } 
    }
}
```

and then

```
obj.Group.GetAllSubscriptions()
```

If you need to run on browsers older than IE9 you will need to polyfill:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map